# Dynamic Forms—Proper way to Setup Database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, codeigniter

A client for which I'm working on a web app needs various applications for some services they offer. They'd like to be able to manage/create these applications themselves. I'm having trouble figuring out a best way to accomplish this as each of their applications will contain different numbers of fields of different types. Some will need to store some large chunks of text (essays), others will possibly need fields for uploading documents.

With some javascript I've created a form to allow them to dynamically build a form for their applications. What is the best way to store the information about these form elements in my database?

Once these forms are created is there a reasonable way to store/retrieve the submitted data in a table? Is this just asking too much and it would be insane to maintain?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for something easy, which will dynamically create tables as objects without any pre-setup or database knowledge, I'd suggest using an ORM.  My favorite is [RedBeanPHP.](http://redbeanphp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Zend Form](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/Factory.php) might be a good starting point for inspiration, specifically [Zend\Form\Factory](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#creation-via-factory). As you can see, you can just pass in an Array which can come from anywhere.

Anthony.